# difference between success function and Then function in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Hi Can any one please help me about this service call methods in angular Js.

what is the difference between Success function and Then Function?

Which function is use in which condition

Comment: the `httpPromise` is what `$http` returns.  So it is in fact what you are asking about.  The question linked is a really good answer to your question.

Comment: Siva: You are not behaving properly here. You should know that very well. @Malkus has provided a very helpful duplicate link. Before giving "negative to" someone's comment, you "must have a look"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular.js we have ***$http*** and ***$q*** , both returns the **promise** object.

The main difference between **$httpPromise** and **$q.defer().promise** is that **$http** provide you two more function **success** and **error**.
So you can't use success and error to a function returning $q.defer().promise.

One difference in context of $http is as [Sacho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694215/sacho) explained below.

Answer (score 4):

As per the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

The `.then()` function is the standard way to register callbacks for when a promise has been resolved - see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q for angular's implementation of promises.

The promise returned by `$http` is a promise for a Response:

```
$http.get('http://example.com').then(function successCallback(response) {
   response.data, response.status, and so on
})
```

Oftentimes, all you need from the Response is just the data. The callbacks registered via `.success()` will receive just `data`:

```
$http.get('http://example.com').success(function successCallback(data) {
   data.??? depending on what you return
})
```

Comment: So, why then use q service. What is the point if http returns promise which can receive response object.

Comment: Well, angular handles many of the async operations for you - you can make ajax requests via `$http`, you can set timers via `$timeout` and `$interval`, which all return promises .  But a few examples where you would need `$q` would be: 1) `$q.when(value)` - you already have the value, but want to maintain a consistent return type(e.g. caching). You might also want to compose promises - `$q.all(manypromises)` creates a promise that is resolved when *all of them* are. And of course, any other async operation that you might need to craft a custom deferred for.